# Counting integer solutions to $x^2 + y ^2 < n$

Tags: number-theory, combinatorial-number-theory

How can I count the number of integer solutions, $\mu(n)$, of $x^2+y^2 < n$, and then hopefully look at behavior as $n \to +\infty$?

Answer (score 10):

This is the [Gauss circle problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_circle_problem); you’ll find considerable information there and at [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssCircleProblem.html). The latter has numerous references, and there are more references at [OEIS A000328](http://oeis.org/A000328).

Answer (score 7):

The behaviour as $n\to\infty$ is simpler than counting exactly in the finite case:
You count exactly the integer points in a circle of radius $\sqrt n$. Since the circle is not too "chaotic", the number of points is essentially the area of the circle: $\mu(n)\sim \pi n$.